How to make a bold Z
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Define the outer Z
        \fill[white, draw=black, thick] (-2, 2) rectangle (2, 1); 
        \fill[white, draw=black, thick] (-2, -2) rectangle (2, -1);
        \fill[white, draw=black, thick] (1, 1) --(-2, -1)  -- (-1, -1) -- (2, 1) -- cycle; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I want to remove the connecting portion of black lines as follows. How to get a better Z? I have to make Z so that I can change the \fill light and transparent colour in place of white 

There is no rectangle in that figure, so do not use it.

Try to draw the area with only a single path, like this for example:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Define the outer Z
        \fill[white, draw=black, thick] 
            (-1, -1) -- (2, 1) |- (-2, 2) |- 
            (1, 1) -- (-2, -1) |- (2, -2) |- cycle; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


